# C# - How can I do a simple query in Entity Framework using lambda?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have an Entity Framework model semi-working right now, but I'm having trouble performing a query to return database records with a `Where()` clause.

I am trying to line:

```
db.BlackstoneUsers.Where(u => u.Email == User.Email);
```

but I get the exception:

> Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

I think this should be simple, but I'm just learning Entity and LINQ/Lambda.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: What is `User` or `User.Email`? Is it just a straight string, or is it some sort of database object as well?

Comment: @StevenVondruska `User` is a database model and `User.Email` is a string

Comment: how are you running the program?

Comment: @Jonesy It's a web project run in Azure

Comment: Can you show us the whole method where you are using the line? Or an abbreviated version?

Comment: So `User` is a class? Or is `User` a variable?

Comment: @StevenVondruska `User` is a class

Comment: You cannot `Shift+F9` over a lambda expression. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to check this in the watch window in the debugger? The debugger doesn't support lambda expressions.

Comment: Believe it or not, the answer below from @Kyle did the trick! Seems odd, but it definitely fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the email outside the call

```
var email = User.Email
db.BlackstoneUsers.Where(u => u.Email == email);
```

Comment: What would this accomplish?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel the email would be converted to a constantexpression which can be translated by the EntityFramework code

Comment: @brett only send constants to your EntityFramework expressions

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but what are you doing with the object?

Just this code will not work.

```
db.BlackstoneUsers.Where(u => u.Email == email);
```

But what if you do like

```
var something = db.BlackstoneUsers.Where(u => u.Email == User.email);
```